# Exit a module, but not the entire NodeJS process

Tags: node.js, callback, gulp, exit, abort

I have a complex parsing/text processing module which sometimes, deep within callback chains, hit unrecoverable errors and essentially do:

```
console.log('Things went bad. Aborting.');
process.exit(1);
```

I'd like to call this module from a gulp file. Doing this with `child_exec()` works ok. But perhaps it would be more elegant to `require()` the module, then make a regular call.

The problem is that calling `process.exit()` in this scenario causes the entire process to quit, which I don't want: the gulpfile should gracefully handle the error.

Is there any way to achieve this that doesn't require effectively tracking an `abort` flag and making sure no processing continues after it has been raised?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to "abort a module".  Once your code is loaded, the interpreter doesn't keep track of where the code came form.  It's just code at that point.  Plus modules or the callers of modules can have state and it is you, the coder, who is responsible for maintaining proper state when error conditions happen.

This sounds like you really just need to code proper error handling all the way back to an appropriate level.  There are no magic shortcuts for proper error handling.  There are no module do-overs.  Some things you could do:

1. Throw an exception from within the module and handle the exception appropriately.  This would only work with synchronous code, not with async code.
2. Propagate errors all the way back through all callers so the error can be dealt with at the appropriate level in your code.
3. If you're using async code, then use promises to help you propagate the errors back to the right level.
4. Handle all errors appropriately as you return back results.

You should NOT get yourself into a non-recoverable error if you code carefully and thoroughly.

If it is callback chains that are making it hard to propagate errors back appropriately, then promises can make this a ton easier since they provide a built-in error propagation mechanism that is very easy to use.  In fact, when writing production-quality code where you need to handle every possible error, I find the async error handling of promises to be their most valuable feature - saving both time and energy and improving the quality of my code.  They are useful for other reason too, but the async error handling would probably benefit you greatly for this particular project.  You will have to "promisify" every async operation to take full advantage.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. This is one of those codebases that started a bit quirk and dirty and has grown bigger than expected. I normally use promises (in browser-side code) but didn't in this case for no particularly good reason. Going with `when.liftAll(fs)` now.